# How to convert reactive Publisher to simple Stream in Scala?

Tags: scala, reactive-streams

Is it possible convert [`org.reactivestreams.Publisher`](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.2-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Publisher.html) instance to [`scala.Stream`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html)? If it is possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will something like the following work for you?

```
val queue: java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue[T] = ... // TODO: choose appropriate BlockingQueue implementation

publisher.subscribe(new Subscriber[T] {
  override def onNext(t: T): Unit = { queue.put(t) }

  // TODO: implement other Subscriber methods
}

val stream = Stream.continually(queue.take)
```

Comment: That won't work. Subscriber's `onNext` will never be called

Comment: I have no idea why. Dare to explain?

Comment: I return stream from function and then can only work with it. `queue.poll` is called when I trying to get values from the stream. The queue is empty

Comment: My fault, sorry. You need a `BlockingQueue`, I've changed the answer.

Comment: Can you explain why this change should fix incorrect work?

Comment: `take` is blocking, it waits for an element in the queue if it's empty. The queue will do the job queues are supposed to do, I mean buffering messages. You said above that `onNext` will never be called. I still do not get why, but hardly can provide help here, b/c I know nothing about "reactive streams".